# Deserialising JSON using nested class in C#. Where to create instance of object?

Tags: c#, .net, json, class, deserialization

I have a JSON with the following structure:

```
{
    "firstname" : "Roger",
    "lastname" : "Moore",
    "age" : 89,
    "isAlive" : false,
    "address" :
    {
        "streetAddress" : "1 Main Street",
        "city" : London",
        "postCode" : "N1 3XX"
    }
}
```

I also have a C# program which utilises the Newtonsoft JSON library, to try and deserialise this JSON. I have created a class as follows:

```
class JSONPerson
    {
        public String firstName { get; set; }
        public String lastName { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public bool isAlive { get; set; }
        public address addr { get; set; }

        public class address
        {
            public String streetAddress { get; set; }
            public String city { get; set; }
            public String postCode { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Deserialisation is done as follows:

```
JSONPerson jPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONPerson>(strJSON);
```

There is a function debugOutput which prints the output to a textbox. With the following I get a System.NullReferenceException:

```
debugOutput(jPerson.addr.postCode);
```

I understand why this is happening. It is because the nested class has not been instantiated anywhere. However, I am unsure where exactly this must be done.

With a simpler version of the above JSON and class, which omit the address, the above works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that address in your `JSONPerson` class is called `addr` but in your JSON it's called `address`.

Change your JSON like this and all will be fine.

```
{
    "firstname" : "Roger",
    "lastname" : "Moore",
    "age" : 89,
    "isAlive" : false,
    "addr" :
    {
        "streetAddress" : "1 Main Street",
        "city" : London",
        "postCode" : "N1 3XX"
    }
}
```

Comment: by the way city : "London" is missing the starting quotation mark..